# Magento2 Category page with color swatches loading too slow

Tags: magento2, category, configurable-product, performance

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p1 along with  Elastic Load Balancer , My application is hosted in 8GB RAM and 160GB space and MYSQL also hosted on another VM with 8GB ram.

I have 40,000 products which all are virtual products with 500 configurable products. In front end only showing these 500 products with color swatches. When i hit the category pages, its almost taking 12-16 seconds to load those pages.

I want to increase the performance of category pages. What type of optiomizations i can do here. I googled and tried

```
Disable count on layer navigation
Enabled HTTP2
Enabled CDN for static and media files
```

But none of the above not speed up my page. Also tried with mod_pagespeed but it crashed my admin panel of magento2 products. So i disabled that mod_pagespeed.

Comment: Identified the issue , Layernavigation is taking too much time. I want to load layer navigation after page load . How can i do it? any idea?

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please provide data from FRONT END and MySQL hosted on another VM, please.  Are you using 'dedicated' or 'shared' servers?  URL, if allowed to share the name, please ?

Comment: Would you like to proceed with server workload tuning analysis?  Still need data requested on Oct 17, 2020.